# Git store current commit hash in file

Tags: php, git

I have a web app that's stored on git.

Whenever tester is about to test it, he pulls the version from branch and builds it.

Sometimes the build doesn't succeed and there's no error (or he doesn't do CTRL + F in the browser).

I would like to store commit hash every time the app is pulled in a file readable by the app, can be json or plain text.

Is there any way to do it? Can't find anything on google.

Comment: What provider are you hosting this on? Github?

Comment: @DelenaMalan GitLab